# Resampling and re-projecting weather satellite image from global view to regional extent

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy, metpy

After reading and plotting the satellite image on the notebook, I am finding it difficult to resample and re-project (projection = PlateCarre) to regional extent (extent = -1, 19, -1, 17). I will appreciate if the Coastline is plotted on the image. I would appreciate if the station called "DNKN" (long= 8.53, lat= 12.05) can be plotted too. The code for reading and plotting the satellite image is below. Kindly edit as deemed fit. Thanks.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
ax = plt.axes()
sat_image1 = '2014_06_16_16Z.jpg'
df = plt.imread(sat_image1)
ax.set_axis_off()
plt.imshow(df)
plt.show()
```

Link to satellite image ('2014_06_16_16Z.jpg') is
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fE4V9aHIklGdv7NizQommdWzAvR6DpUN/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Linked image has been deleted from Google drive

Comment: Also, you are not passing any information on the location of this image (NSEW boundaries), have you checked similar questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22386876/cartopy-how-to-add-an-image-on-top-of-map

Comment: @Marcos, please click on the link again. The image is available now. My sincere apology for any inconvenience.

Comment: @Marcos Thanks for sharing the link. I have researched several other materials similar to the one you shared. See this:  https://python-kurs.github.io/sommersemester_2019/units/S01E06.html, but I still find it uneasy solving that task. I would really appreciate any further assistance. If there is any more question, do not hesitate to reach out to me. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You have several issues here with little evidence of research and, to my mind, this is not specific enough for a stackoverflow question. I strongly suggest you read stackoverflow luminary Jon Skeet's [article on asking a good question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Specific issues to address:

1. You are not using cartopy to create a georeferenced map
2. You have not attempted to define the origin coordinate reference system of your image
3. You have not attempted to convert to your desired coordinate reference system.
4. You have not referenced any of the many tools specifically designed for this purpose

Adding geo-referenced imagery to a map is a non-trivial task. I think you need to do some more reading and practice before you will be able to solve your issue. There are some great resources out there. You should start by ensuring you understand what a coordinate reference system is. This will help you understand why importing the image you included makes little sense.

If you search for `cartopy add satellite image` you will quickly find articles that show you how:

The cartopy documentation has a page for [plotting an image on a map](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/v0.13/matplotlib/advanced_plotting.html) with [source code](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/v0.13/matplotlib/advanced_plotting-3.py)

An extensive [blog post](https://geonetcast.wordpress.com/2019/07/29/python-satellite-imagery-quickstart/) with a full guide to plotting whole earth imagery in cartopy

[Another blog](https://www.net-analysis.com/blog/cartopyimages.html) that shows how to plot a satellite image from a WMS on a cartopy map with full Python code.

Please take some time to understand the cartopy library and the nature of GIS. Copy some examples from the cookbook and adapt them to your needs, read GIS blog posts, mess around with some practice data sets. When you have a specific well defined issue, come back and ask a new question.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, @marcos. I will expand my research with some of the links you provided. Nevertheless, I had previously done a lot reading on cartopy library and documentation, and I am not new to GIS. What I am trying to achieve with python I have already implemented with ArcGIS10 and trust me, this is not a random question. Again, thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

@Dayo, did you solve your problem? This can be done i you define the proper coordinate systems for the map projection and image data transformation. The starting image is not the best quality, so any images generated from it will be limited to the same quality. That may not be an issue since your regional (map) extent is focused on Nigeria.

Let's start by plotting the original image with the coastlines (in blue) on a Geostationary map projection (same as the image). I get the axis extents from the map so I can "trim" the image with the `extent=` parameter in `plt.imshow()`. (Note: coordinates on a Geostationary are **not** (longitude, latitude). For reasons  I don't understand, I had to increase the values slightly to align the coastlines. Run this and you should get image shown below the code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

sat_image1 = '2014_06_16_16Z.jpg'
df = plt.imread(sat_image1)

map_proj = ccrs.Geostationary(central_longitude=0.0)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax = plt.axes(projection=map_proj)
ax.coastlines(color='blue')

# Map extent in Geostationary coordinates:
map_extent_sat = ax.get_extent(crs=map_proj)    
img_extent_sat = [1.03*x for x in map_extent_sat]

plt.imshow(df, extent=img_extent_sat)
```

[image: Satellite image on Geostationary projection]

Now let's create your regional map on the Mercator projection. The process is similar, with a different coordinate systems for map projection (in `plt.axes()`)and image transformation in `plt.imshow()`. Coordinates of extent objects must be transformed to the map projection (Mercator). Image extent coordinates go from Geostationary to Mercator, and map extent goes from lat/lon (Geodetic) to Mercator. You could do this with inline calculations. I do it a lot, so have a function for simplicity/readability. The rest of the code is basic `matplotlib` functionality. Comments should explain those steps. Image of resulting regional map follows.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

def transform_extent_pts(extent_pts, map_proj, pt_crs):
    
    xul, yul = map_proj.transform_point(
        x = extent_pts[0],
        y = extent_pts[3],
        src_crs = pt_crs)
    
    xlr, ylr = map_proj.transform_point(
        x = extent_pts[1],
        y = extent_pts[2],
        src_crs = pt_crs)

    return [xul, xlr, ylr, yul]


sat_image1 = '2014_06_16_16Z.jpg'
df = plt.imread(sat_image1)

# re-project to Mercator 
map_proj = ccrs.Mercator()

# Image extent in Geostationary coordinates:
data_crs = ccrs.Geostationary(central_longitude=0.0)
ax2 = plt.axes(projection=data_crs)
img_extent_sat = ax2.get_extent(crs=data_crs)    
img_extent_sat = [1.03*x for x in img_extent_sat]
# Convert to Mercator
img_extent_merc = transform_extent_pts(img_extent_sat, map_proj, ccrs.Geodetic())
plt.close() 

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax = plt.axes(projection=map_proj)
ax.coastlines(color='blue')
ax.gridlines(color='black', alpha=0.5, linestyle='--', linewidth=0.75, draw_labels=True)

# Map extent in degrees (PlateCarree) coordinates:
map_extent_deg = (50., -20., -40., 40.) # African continent
map_extent_deg = (-1, 19, -1, 17)
# Convert to Mercator
map_extent_merc = transform_extent_pts(map_extent_deg, map_proj, ccrs.Geodetic())
ax.set_extent(map_extent_merc, map_proj)
    
plt.imshow(df, origin='upper', transform=data_crs, extent=img_extent_sat)

# Add a marker at station location
sta_name = "DNKN"
sta_lon, sta_lat = (8.53, 12.05) 
plt.plot(sta_lon, sta_lat, marker='o', color='red', markersize=8,
         alpha=0.7, transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
plt.text(sta_lon, sta_lat+0.25, sta_name, ha='center', fontsize=18,
         color='red', transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
```

[image: Satellite image projected to regional Mercator projection]