# Resampling and re-projecting weather satellite image

Tags: python, cartopy

The current question is somewhat similar to a resampling question on:

> [Resample question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65553354/resampling-and-re-projecting-weather-satellite-image-from-global-view-to-regiona)

However, my specific problem is that I only have a partial satellite image and not the full image. As a result, I'm not sure how to proceed. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

def transform_extent_pts(extent_pts, map_proj, pt_crs):
    
    xul, yul = map_proj.transform_point(
        x = extent_pts[0],
        y = extent_pts[3],
        src_crs = pt_crs)
    
    xlr, ylr = map_proj.transform_point(
        x = extent_pts[1],
        y = extent_pts[2],
        src_crs = pt_crs)

    return [xul, xlr, ylr, yul]


sat_image1 = ROOT
df = plt.imread(sat_image1)

# re-project to Mercator 
map_proj = ccrs.Mercator()

# Image extent in Geostationary coordinates:
data_crs = ccrs.Geostationary(central_longitude=0.0)
ax2 = plt.axes(projection=data_crs)
img_extent_sat = ax2.get_extent(crs=data_crs)    
img_extent_sat = [1.03*x for x in img_extent_sat]
#img_extent_sat=[-32.150361957, 30.150361957, 7.150361956, 42.150361956]
# Convert to Mercator
img_extent_merc = transform_extent_pts(img_extent_sat, map_proj, ccrs.Geodetic())
plt.close() 

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax = plt.axes(projection=map_proj)
ax.coastlines(color='blue')
ax.gridlines(color='black', alpha=0.5, linestyle='--', linewidth=0.75, draw_labels=True)

# Map extent in degrees (PlateCarree) coordinates:
map_extent_deg = (50., -20., -40., 40.) # African continent
map_extent_deg = (-31, 38.009232, 2.880476, 42)
# Convert to Mercator
map_extent_merc = transform_extent_pts(map_extent_deg, map_proj, ccrs.Geodetic())
ax.set_extent(map_extent_merc, map_proj)
    
plt.imshow(df, origin='upper', transform=data_crs, extent=img_extent_sat)
```

[image]

The main issue I'm facing is that the projection of my data seems to be incorrect, and there might also be a small misalignment. I'm now wondering how I can change the projection of my data. Could you provide some guidance on how to accomplish this?
I've tried a few things, but unfortunately the image is only available in PNG format. The "transform" function, such as using "geostationary," doesn't seem to work with this format. Are there any other options available? Can the projection be changed afterwards, or is that not possible? I assume that the exact coordinates can be obtained by shifting the image.
Perhaps the two red dots can be helpful. I know their coordinates, and they should align with the two white squares:

```
plt.plot(sta_lon, sta_lat, marker='o', color='red', markersize=8,
        alpha=0.7, transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
plt.text(sta_lon, sta_lat+0.25, sta_name, ha='center', fontsize=18,
         color='red', transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
```

Comment: If it's a geotiff, you can get the extent (geotransform) and projection from the metadata. You're assigning the projection now as "PlateCarree", are you sure that's correct and the image isn't (still) in the MSG geostationary projection for example? You probably wont get an answer since it's not reproducible without the data.

Comment: hi... i use cartopy for that problem... the image is a png image... so i have to try which extent i should use... The main problem is actually to convert the png image (geostationary) and merge this to contour coastlines.